# Create nested menu via 3 json files

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to make a nested menu from 3 `json` files, but In the first step I stuck, it return nothing:

```
var json = {};
$.getJSON("/api/category.json", function(data){
    json.category = data;
});

$.getJSON("/api/subcat.json", function(data){
    json.subcat = data;
});

$.getJSON("/api/subsubcat.json", function(data){
    json.subsubcat = data;
});

$.each(json, function(i,v) {
    console.log(json[i]); // it return nothing
});
```

But when I tried `console.log(json)` it return object, but even when I get `console.log(json.category)` It return nothing, no error in console log.

If I solve this issue I want to make a nested menu with this three `json` file in a loop, something like this:

```js
var obj = '';

$.each(json.category, function(i, v) {
  obj += '<li data-id="' + data[i]['id'] + '"><a href="/browse/' + currentCity + '/' + slugSearch(data[i]['name']) + '">' + data[i]['name'] + '</a><ul>';

  $.each(json.subcat, function(i, v) {
    if (json.subcat["cat_id"] == json.category["id"]) {
      obj += '<li data-id="' + data[i]['id'] + '"><a href="/browse/' + currentCity + '/' + slugSearch(data[i]['name']) + '">' + data[i]['name'] + '</a></li>';
    }
  });

  obj += '</ul>';

  // also subsub cat

  $('.simulate-cat').append($(obj));
});
```

```html
<ul class="simulate-cat"></ul>
```

Is this way right to make nested menu?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you're not waiting for the requests to complete. Because of that `json` properties aren't populated yet

It should look like this

```
$.when($.getJSON("/api/category.json"), $.getJSON("/api/subcat.json") , $.getJSON("/api/subsubcat.json")).done(function( a1, a2, a3 ) {
  json.category = a1[0];
  json.subcat = a2[0];
  json.subsubcat = a3[0];
  // create menu here
});
```

See [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) for more info about how to wait for multiple async callbacks